# Download file in Batch

Tags: batch-file, download

I have a batch file. I would like to download a file in it and choose where to put it. I do not want it to have any dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Use this command:

```
powershell -command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://example.org/path.ext', 'P:\ath\to\file')"
```